# Books to read after Computational Complexity: A Modern Approach?

Tags: complexity-theory, books

To be honest, I have not yet read this book, but it's fun to plan ahead. If I am able to read through the entirety of this book and solve all the problems, are there books to dive deeper into the theory? Or is this a good enough introduction to just start jumping into research papers?

Comment: There are a handful of monographs on specific areas, but generally speaking, there is no textbook on computational complexity beyond Arora–Barak.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Thanks! What if I'm really interested in learning more about P = NP (I'm basic what can I say).